# Securing Office web content from redistribution without RMS

Tags: security, ms-office, drm, rights-management

I’m looking for a mechanism that can be used to distribute Microsoft Office content over the web without using Rights Managements Services whilst minimising the ability for it to be printed or redistributed. I know any solution is always going to be a compromise and never entirely secure but I’d be interested in any mechanisms which increase the degree of difficulty to redistribute. The frontrunner at the moment is to use Flashpaper with the print and selection tools disabled and convert the documents to this format as required.

The business need to provide sales reps with material about products which can not easily be redistributed externally in electronic format.

Has anyone come up with something more elegant? Any other thoughts about limiting the ability to redistribute without investing in other DRM technologies?

Answer (score 0):

Question - are there any Open Source tools that read Flashpaper?  Bear in mind that any restrictions that exist in the tool to read the document are only useful when there is no more permissive tool handy.  If any tool becomes popular for limiting document use like that, there will be tools to grab the content.  They may be illegal under the DMCA, but they will exist.

Unless all you want to do is discourage those who are not tech-savvy, you're going to have to go for DRM.

BTW, what is the intended use for this?

Comment: Thanks David, in this case we're talking about internally distributed material where we want to minimise the risk of redistribution to competitors.